# How to explain a dialog naturally to a friend

Tags: dialogue

I'm wondering what's the proper way to explain a dialog between two people, to a friend. For example saying :

> So friend A came up and told us "Hello", so I replied "hello" back and he asked how I was

I often want to say things like that to explain something but always end up using basic words without knowing if it's natural or not, for example :

> ある友達がおはよーって言って来て、でおはようって答えて、元気か聞いてくれた。

It sounds really wordy and all these て forms don't sound good to me but I don't know what I should be using. Also I don't know if I should be using 答える、返事 or another one. And can I use くれる here? Thanks

Comment: 友達がやってきてハローって言って、私はハローって言って、調子どうって聞かれた！

Answer (score 7):

How about using ～から、～たら etc.

> 友達がおはよーって言ってきて、おはようって言っ**たら**、元気かって聞いてくれた。/聞いてきた。
>   友達がおはよーって言ってきた**から**、おはようって返事し**たら**/答え**たら**、元気かって言ってくれた。/言ってきた。
>   etc...

or the passive voice (to use the same subject(=私) for the sequence of sentences)...

> 友達におはよーって言**われ**て、おはようって言ったら、元気かって聞**かれ**た。
>   友達におはよーって言**われ**たから、おはようって返事したら/答えたら、元気かって言**われ**た。
>   etc...